# I want to make Saved File Dialog for a saved file in wpf c#, is it possible?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio

I have a link label in WPF C#, i want, on clicking that label, it should copy a saved file from specific folder, and save the file to some location wherever user wants to save, just like we do Save As in any software application. In SaveFileDialog class i can see that there is no option to open or copy a saved file and then to save some where else, please let me know how can i do so.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can use Open File Dialog and Save File Dialog in sequence in this scenario

First use Open File Dialog to ask user which file to copy

Then use Save File Dialog to save copied file to user defined location

Comment: can you please explain more, how?

Comment: i dont want user to select file, there is a link and i just want to pick file from there and save it wherever user wants.

Comment: Then simply take location from user through save file dialog and copy the file (whose address you already have) to user defined location

Comment: If you want to know how save file dialog works take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sfezx97z.aspx or http://www.dotnetperls.com/savefiledialog

Answer (score 0):

The only pupose of a `SaveFileDialog` is to let the user choose a path and to get confirmation for overwriting existing files, *everything else is your responisbility*.

Comment: I have asked, let me know how can i do so?

Comment: It's all just basic file manipulation, see the [`System.IO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.aspx) namespace.